# AFNetworking + JSON and getting server status

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, afnetworking

I'm trying to call data from a website using JSON.

So far I can manage to get the full data. However, I'm trying to get a specific option from the JSON input.

What I'm getting:

```
{
"servers": {
"CA Servers": {
"Can One": {
"status": "medium"
},

"Can Two": {
"status": "medium"
}
},

"US Servers": {
"US One": {
"status": "down"
},
"US Two": {
"status": "high"
}
}
}
}
```

I'm wondering how I can pull just the "medium" from Can One and the "High" from US Two, or the "Down" from US One, and throw it into my storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using AFNetworking and `AFJSONRequestOperation`, in your `success` callback you should have a JSON object like this:

```
...
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // Use JSON as an NSDictionary
    NSString *status = JSON[@"servers"][@"CA Servers"][@"Can One"][@"status"];
...
```

You can then use the `status` variable in the storyboard. Also remember that if you access the dictionary using my example, you should check that the structure exists. Otherwise, if any of the fields does not exist, the accessor would return `nil` and the application would break.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5 and later, you can use the following code to get those values.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *arrayServers = [dictionary valueForKey:@"servers"];
```